# How to write a function 'repeated' in Scheme that returns a new function applied to an operand n times

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to write a function 'repeated' in Scheme as an exercise in understanding lambdas.

This function takes an operation and a number as arguments and returns a lambda that applies the operation to an operand.

An example invocation looks like this:

```
((repeated print 3) 'hello)
hello
hello
hello
=> "done"
```

Here is my attempt, but it doesn't work and I've spent almost an hour scratching my head trying to figure out why:

```
(define (repeated operation n)
    (lambda (operand)
        (define (repeat combop m)
            (if (= m 0)
                "done"
                (begin   
                    (combop)
                    (repeat combop (- m 1))
                )
            )
        )
        (repeat (operation operand) n)
    )
)
```

It returns this

```
((repeated print 3) 'hello) 
hello
=> Error: #<undef> is not a function [(anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), print, (anon), print, (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon), (anon)]
```

What is the mistake in my implementation?

---

Thanks for the answers.

After some more thinking I figured out there are two different possible problems here and I wasn't clear on which one I was trying to solve.

To repeat the same operation n times, one correct implementation would be this:

```
(define (do-n-times operation n)
    (if (= n 0)
        "done"
        (begin
            (operation)
            (do-n-times operation (- n 1))
        )
    )
)
```

An example run:

```
(define (say-hello)
    (print 'hello)
)
(do-n-times say-hello 5)
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
=> "done"
```

However, a different problem is to successively apply a transformation to a property, each time applying the transformation to the result of the previous. This is the problem I was actually attempting to write a solution for.

So the solution is as follows:

To repeat an operation n times, each time using the result as the new operand for the operation, a sample implementation might look like this:

```
(define (repeated operation n)
    (lambda (operand)
        (define (repeat operation result m)
            (if (= m 0)
                result
                (repeat operation (operation result) (- m 1))
            )
        )
        (repeat operation operand n)
    )
)
```

An example run:

```
(define (divide-by-2 n)
    (/ n 2)
)
((repeated divide-by-2 3) 16)
=> 2
```

Which divides n by 2 three times, starting at n = 16 and each time applying the operation to the result of the previous. So we get (/ (/ (/ 16 2) 2) 2).

Comment: After writing "I wasn't clear on which one I was trying to solve," you described another related question.  Which one *are* you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I was actually trying to solve the second example i.e. an operation applied repeatedly to the result.

Comment: It looks like you've got a solution in the question, don't you?

Comment: Yeah, I originally posted this solution as an answer but it was deleted by a moderator and merged into the question instead.

Comment: Well, it didn't really answer the question that was asked.  It's also not clear whether or now there's actually still a question being asked...  Is everything resolved now, or is there still a question?

Comment: The problem was, I wasn't clear in my own head which problem I was trying to solve. Turns out, the correct solution IS the final one that appears in my answer above.

TL;DR yes it is resolved now.

Comment: Since the question in its current form isn't likely to be very useful to other users (since the question asks one thing, but the answers are talking about another), you should probably consider either: (i) cleaning up the question to be what you actually want to ask and posting your answer as an answer proper; or (ii) delete the question.

Comment: I did post the answer as an answer proper, but a moderator moved it into the question.

Comment: I think it got moved into the question because a lot of your post wasn't an answer, but was a new question, which you subsequently answered.  The problem is that none of that content was really an answer to the question that was actually posted.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to **repeat** is supposed to be a function (since you call **(combop)**, but you're passing **(operation operand)**.  The simplest way to fix this is to initially call **repeat** with a lambda function that calls **operation** with **operand**:

```
(define (repeated operation n)
    (lambda (operand)
        (define (repeat combop m)
            (if (= m 0)
                "done"
                (begin   
                    (combop)
                    (repeat combop (- m 1))
                )
            )
        )
        (repeat (lambda () (operation operand)) n) ; *** repeat with a function 
    )
)
```

That doesn't require you to change the definition of **repeat**.  Alternatively, you could take the approach in [Le Petit Prince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26843772/1281433) and move the call *into* in the definition of **repeat**.

In both cases, you're using a local definition and then immediately calling it, and that's typically more cleanly written with a named **let** (using my answer and Le Petit Prince's answer):

```
(define (repeated operation n)
    (lambda (operand)
        (let repeat ((combop (lambda () (operation operand)))
                     (m n))
            (if (= m 0)
                "done"
                (begin   
                    (combop)
                    (repeat combop (- m 1)))))))
```

```
(define (repeated operation n)
  (lambda operand
    (let repeat ((m n))
      (when (positive? m)
        (apply operation operand)
        (repeat (- m 1))))))
```